# Pandoc: markdown to docx with latex equations as embedded images

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

Is it possible to get Pandoc to produce a .docx file from a markdown file which includes Latex equations, so that the equations are rendered and embedded as images in the Word document, instead of being rendered using the native Word equation objects?

I'd be happy with either a pure Pandoc solution, or one that links a few utilities which could be automated in a makefile

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/CvnPIiWUc-Q):

```
pandoc --webtex -t html | pandoc -f html -o my.docx
```